# Is a Treeset a language agnostic data structure?

Tags: treeset

I'm just trying to research lesser known data structures, and when I search for Treeset only Java related resources come up.

Should non-Java developers be expected to know what it is? Is it an actual data structure?

Answer (score 0):

All data-structures are language agnostic. They might happen to be implement in one or more languages, but that's irrelevant.

It's kind of like asking "Is the Eiffel tower a material-agnostic building?". Well *the* Eiffel tower is steel, but nothing stops you from building one out of popsicle sticks.

`java.util.TreeSet<E>` is specific to Java (or JVM languages that inter-operate with Java), yes, but nothing stops you from implementing the same data structure in other languages.

Though different languages might have different names for the same thing.

E.g. what Java calls an `ArrayList` is an `Array` in Swift, a `list` in Python, a `std::vector` in C++, or `std::vec` in Rust.

> Should non-Java developers be expected to know what it is?

Yeah, probably. Tree-based alternatives to HashMaps and HashSets have their niche uses, and it would be expected knowledge to at least be aware of their general pro/cons and approximately how they work.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but when Treeset only brings Java results, then I start wondering what the disconnect is. Found out it's actually a red-black tree. A treeset? well that's just a name it seems like, and the java implementation is hidden so it's not much help imo.

Comment: @alexr101 Admittedly, I'd say the Java standard library is more "batteries included" than most, especially w.r.t. data structures. "Found out it's actually a red-black tree." I don't think the Java spec makes any such guarantee. It just  establishes a set of time/space complexity reqs, which JDK implementers are free to implement as they see fit. You can see the OpenJDK impl of TreeSet here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk16/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java Which looks like it's just a wrapper around `TreeMap` by default, which does happen to be a red-black tree.